# What should I do with the ground wire from my light fixture when there's no ground in the box?

Tags: ceiling-fan, grounding

The ceiling light/fan I want to install has a short GREEN wire. It looks ready to be twisted onto another wire. There is NO ground (bare copper or another green wire) coming out of the ceiling box. What do I attach the short green wire that came with the fan/light to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do if there are only two wires coming from my ceiling electrical box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29459/what-do-i-do-if-there-are-only-two-wires-coming-from-my-ceiling-electrical-box)

Comment: @isherwood That accepted answer did not discuss the ground and was dated prior to the current code that allows a new ground to be pulled. Guess there are a lot of non electricians upvoting or just that there was a link.

Comment: Fair enough. I suspect that there's a better duplicate to be found.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer 
or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

This wire is usually connected to a bare wire ground if available, if not available and the box is metal connect it to the box. If you do not have an equipment ground the wire is not used.

Current code allows a ground to be added as long as it comes from the same panel that feeds this circuit (it can come from another circuit if grounded and fed from the same panel)