# Porch light over heating and stopped working second light fixture

Tags: light-fixture

I am by no means an electrician, but for my new light fixture I did follow the following schematic - [How should I connect the ground wire for my light fixture?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20351/how-should-i-connect-the-ground-wire-for-my-light-fixture)

The old fixture kept burning out the bulb so I replaced it with a nice https://www.lightingdirect.com/heath-zenith-hz-4300-4-light-360-degree-motion-activated-outdoor-flush-mount-ceiling-fixture/p2675820

Was working fine and please note I installed:

- White to White
- Black to Black
- And ground to bare ground wire (Actually ran the ground wire around the screw, which I am not sure if that is correct)

Now after installation the light was working fine, but now a couple of months later the light is glowing on an off (poltergeist) and I took it down and there looks like some brown burn marks.  Is it time to call in an electrician?

I have thus turned out the light and not using till I get this resolved.  I do not need to burn down our home.

Comment: Picture showing the burn marks would be helpful.   Sounds like the electronics in the motion head are the real problem tho. While Heath zenith was once a quality brand that offered innovation anymore there stuff is kinda more in the cheap junk category.

Comment: Are you using bulbs that have a higher wattage than the fixture is rated for?

Comment: Where are you seeing burn marks?

Comment: The brown burn marks where when I took the fixture down to check the wire connections.

Comment: Yes 4 25 watt bulbs - Bulb type: 4 -Type B10, 25 Watt Candelabra base (Not Included)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the light fixture.  The motion detector died.  Replaced at lowe's and all is good.