# How do I wire a light fixture to these wires?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, old-house

[image]I have 5 wires out of my ceiling from an old light fixtures. I don’t know how it was wired and I’m trying to wire a new fixture in. Can someone help?

Comment: Start out by posting some pictures of the ceiling box, fixture and switch box so we can see what you see.

Comment: We can't help without some pictures and maybe colours of the wires.  If you check the switch wires when you have the breaker off that will help also.  It will be probably be simple to help you if you can provide the extra information.

Comment: There’s 5 wires with a cloth like insulation 2 are coming out of one side and 3 from the other side there is a switch that controls this fixture which wires do I but together to put up the new black abs whit and copper wire fixture?

Comment: Use Electrical Tester Pen, to find the hot wire. Do not use those contactless tester types. You probably have only one hot wire. That looks like serial wiring. Two come in, two go to next box, one is ground. you can try the hot wire with any of other 3 except ground to connect to a light bulb.

Comment: I would guess, the one on the right and the second one from th left were connected together. The one all the way to the left and the center-left one are connected to the fixture. I assume the longest one is ground.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I connect the ground wire for my light fixture?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20351/how-should-i-connect-the-ground-wire-for-my-light-fixture)

Comment: The insulation looks really frayed on the black wire and the white wire toward the front of the picture. that's going to be a serious problem if it's just shoved up back into the box.

Comment: OOPS! I don't see how anyone can really answer this.